# What is the name of the icon for usb drives in Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, python, themes, icons, pygtk

I am developing a PyGtk application that I would like to display the image for a USB stick from the user's theme. However, I cannot seem to pin down the name of the icon, and Google is no help. Consider the following code:

```
 import pygtk
 pygtk.require('2.0')
 require gtk

 icon_theme = gtk.icon_theme_get_default()
 icon_theme.has_icon('firefox') #True
 icon_theme.has_icon('google-chrome') #True
 icon_theme.has_icon('usb') #False. I have also tried "drive", and "usb-drive".
```

- Can you suggest a query?
- Is the USB stick icon discoverable this way? Should I look elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the function list_icons():

```
icons=icon_theme.list_icons()
for icon in icons:
    if 'usb' in icon:
       print icon
```

and the output:

```
drive-removable-media-usb
usbpendrive_unmount
gnome-dev-removable-usb
usb-creator
drive-harddisk-usb
gnome-dev-harddisk-usb
gnome-dev-unknown-usb
usb-creator-gtk
drive-harddisk-usb-symbolic
```

Now take your pic

Comment: I think that should be "icon" in the for loop, and not "icons" :D

Comment: yep... sorry bout that